# How can I make Nginx cache 403 pages?

Tags: nginx

We are using a Java application, Amazon ELB and NGINX. When our Java platform gets an incorrect request it or receives anything that resembles a DDOS, it will throw a 403 error.

The developers want NGINX to cache the 403 errors, so that DDOS-requests won't end up hittin the Java application server.

So how can I make NGINX only cache 403 pages?

Answer (score 0):

You would set

```
proxy_cache_valid 403 1m;
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html?&_ga=1.179671140.1192180146.1425500797#proxy_cache_valid